# Redirecting default printer (which is unknown) to LPT3

Tags: batch-file, printing, vbscript

I'm trying to use the same script "**prnmngr.vbs**" from Microsoft to redirect the default printer to the LP3 port. I guess this is the most effective and standard way to detect default printers that I found so far but no success so far. I would like to keep it really simple using a .cmd file.

The code below will map the default printer using "WMIC" but it will not redirect to any LPT:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%A in (    
  'wmic printer where "default=True" get name /value'
  ) do SET DefaultPrinter=%%A
exit
```

My goal as I said is to Redirect the unknown default printer to the LP3 on the unknown computer and it will be great if the result from prnmngr.vbs  can be parsed somehow in order to map the Default Printer to the LP3 port. Or to modify the prnmngr.vbs to do the usual command :

```
net use lpt3 \\computername\sharedprinter
```

So far I just can't handle the whole VBS coding to do what I need. I got confused with all the functions inside.

The command below will map the printer without any problems only if you have both \Servername and \Sharedprinter  but on my case they will be unknown.

```
Cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -ac -p "\\servername\sharedprinter"
```

The Default printer could be a shared network printer or a USB/WiFi and obviously the computer name will also be unknown. I can't check one by one between 5000 machines or users to search and get their devices to give them a command to map their printers on their own every time they execute their application!

---

I just been told that the name "Imprimant" is the name all the Local Printers shared name will be used so as long as this name doesn't change at all it should be fine. 
But at the moment this script is working only for the 1st case (:Shared) and the Local case is not working at all. If I invert the ERRORLEVEL it will work the (:Local) and Not the (:Shared).

But so far I got a new scrip and it goes like this:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%A in ('wmic printer where "default=True" get name /value ' ) do (
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set DefaultPrinter=%%A
echo %DefaultPrinter% |find "\\"
if ERRORLEVEL EQU 1 (goto Local 
else (
if ERRORLEVEL EQU 0 goto Shared
)

:Shared
net use lpt3 "%DefaultPrinter%"
goto end

:Local
net use lpt3 "\\%computername%\Imprimant"
goto end
)

:end
exit /B
```

Is there something missing?

Comment: Try `'wmic printer where "default=True" get name /value^|findstr "="'` in your `FOR /F` loop and then `echo "%DefaultPrinter%"&pause` just before `exit /B`.

Comment: afaik you do not even have to have the printer mapped before, the net use command will map it anyway so you only need to figure out the default printer the vbs script would not be needed. You can get it using the wmic command or from the registry "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device" the main problem would be, that the default printer might not be named in the correct way. It HAS to be \\<servername>\yshared printer name> for the net use command to work so you might have to figure something depending on the naming convention used

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys I really appreciate that !! 

Well, I'm counting on the fact that the users should already have the Printer mapped, otherwise the script will not work at all.

I also know that Printers could be modified by registry using:

reg ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\PARALLEL PORTS" /v "\DEVICE\PARALLEL2" /t REG_SZ /d "\DOSDEVICES\LPT3" 

So maybe there's something that I'm missing to complete the last piece of this crazy puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Voila, here you go !! The final script works fine.

```
@echo off

if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized
set minimized=true
start /min cmd /C "%~dpnx0"
set minimized=
goto :EOF

:minimized

echo Erasing previous mappings from LTP3...
net use lpt3 /d >nul

echo Detecting Default Printer ...
FOR /F "tokens=1-3* skip=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic printer where "default=True" get name^,servername^,sharename /value ' ) do (
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set DefaultPrinter%%A=%%B
)

echo Default Printer: %DefaultPrinterName%


REM Is this a Local or Network queue?
echo %DefaultPrinterName% |find "\\" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 ( goto Shared ) else ( goto Local )

:Shared
 echo Mapping to LPT3 over %DefaultPrinterServerName%\%DefaultPrinterShareName%
net use lpt3 "%DefaultPrinterServerName%\%DefaultPrinterShareName%"
goto End

:Local
echo Using a Local Printer
IF NOT "%DefaultPrinterShareName%"=="" (
echo Mapping to LPT3 over \\localhost\%DefaultPrinterShareName%
net use lpt3 "\\localhost\%DefaultPrinterShareName%"
) ELSE (
echo Mapping to LPT3 over \\localhost\Impriman
net use lpt3 \\localhost\Impriman
)

:End
exit >> our you can attach other instructions to continue doing some tasks.
```

So this script will do what I meant to do.